# Whcih key is Pure Shores in C# or C# Mixolyain

Tags: chord-theory, key-signatures

I was reading the Wikipedia article about the All Saints song Pure Shores

It said the chord sequence is in the "key of C# mixolydian" - C# - D#m - B - F# - (I get that C# mixolydian is the 5th mode of F#).  It then says "briefly changes to G# major".

But...

Couldn't this also be in the key of C# as a I - ii - bvii - IV - it loops these four chords and then hangs on the V G# before going back.

The sheet music I've seen for this, has the song in D (the tune is in C#) using
I - ii - bvii - IV

Is this all interpretation?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there such thing as "key of C# mixolydian", though it's rather understandable short-hand. It's key of C# major, using C# mixolydian scale. The chords are diatonic in the mixolydian scale and your analysis (I - ii - bvii - VI) looks correct to me.

The melody strongly emphasizes mixolydian scale (with addition of out-of-scale blue note E in the chorus).

The bridge bases on G#7 chord, and G# mixolydian scale, which is a V7 in the key of C#. So it's not really a modulation (change of a key), but rather change of the mode.

Yes, all music theory is an interpretation. But if you have a theory that covers broad range of repertoire, I think it's a better than one that works only in a single song.